# How to download/install paramiko on any sever from Python script?

Tags: python, paramiko

I'm writing a Python script which will be run on many different servers. A vital part of the script relies on the paramiko module, but it's likely that the servers do not have the paramiko package installed already. Everything needs to automated, so all the user has to do is run the script and everything will be completed for them. They shouldn't need to manually install anything.

I've seen that people recommend using Active Python / PyPM, but again, that requires an installation.

**Is there a way to download and install Paramiko (and any package) from a Python script?**

Answer (score 1):

An easy way (and scary) would be to define an external bash file with execution permissions:

**installer.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
pip install paramiko
```

I'm assuming `pip` is installed, but you can concatenate any set of commands in order to install paramiko.

Then from your Python file

**foo.py**

```
try:
   import paramiko
except:
   import subprocess
   subprocess.call('./installer.sh', shell=True)
```

**However** installation issues are not subject of your application, you should considerate using `distutils` to define dependencies in your installation `setup.py` of your package using the `install_requires`

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your Python program in a shell script that checks that `paramiko` is installed and if it isn't installs it before running your program.